# How to collect data from array?

Tags: php

form:

```
<input type="text" name="sample[]" id="sample1"/>
<input type="text" name="sample[]" id="sample2"/>
<input type="text" name="sample[]" id="sample3"/>
....
```

How to collect data from form, and then put each value to mysql?

Comment: I think you want a whole PHP tutorial. This question is too broad.

Comment: Why would you call those using the same name? You should make them different and accessing them with `$_POST['YOUNAMEHERE'];`. MySQL is pretty simple, you should be able to search this up yourself.

Comment: I uses sample[], because form have many fields (sample3, sample4 and etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this to get you started:

```
$sample = is_array( $_POST['sample']) ? $_POST['sample'] : array();

if( count( $sample) > 0)
{
    $sample = array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $sample);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO table (something) 
                VALUES ( "' . implode( '" ), ( "', $sample) . ' ")';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sample_array = $_POST['sample'];
foreach ($sample_array as $sample) {
    //do what you want with it
}
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `$_POST['sample']` is an array.

Answer (score -1):

A simple method is to do the following:

```
$sample = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['sample']));

foreach($sample as $value) {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (foo) VALUE ($value)");
}
```

The syntax may be slightly off but that's the general jest of it.

Comment: -1 There's no guarantee that `$_POST['sample']` is an array, `$value` isn't being escaped so this is prone to SQL injection, and for 1000 entries this will execute 1000 queries, which is highly inefficient when it can be condensed into one query regardless of how many entries are passed to the script.

Comment: As stated in the question's HTML, $_POST['sample'] is an array.  Obviously you'd escape the POST variable, this is common practice.  Why would there be 1000 form fields?